# find inside map method

Tags: javascript, find, mapping

I have a error; it says "Cannot read properties of undefined(reading code)"

Why am I getting this error?

What

```
const completelyDifferentItems = [{code:"1",...},{code:"2",...}...]

      for (let someItems of someCollection) {
        const updatedMenuItems = someItems.otherItems.map(otherItem=> {
          const existItem = completelyDifferentItems.find(differentItem => differentItem.code === otherItem.code)
          if (existItem) {
            otherItem.someKey = existItem.someKey
          }
          return otherItem
        })
       //do smth
      }
```

Comment: `differentItem` or `otherItem` is `undefined`

Comment: where did you get otherItem? ithink you mean to use someItems.map() not like what are you doing